# (Interop.Word) Range.Copy-Range.Paste work slow

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to create a new doc based on another doc. There are multiple iterations with search/replace operations using Range.Text and all work pretty fast. However, in one case I need to copy an entire chapter with all formatting and instead of Range.Text (which resets all formatting) I used Range.Copy and Range.Paste. They work, but for the test chapter with about 450 words, they take up to 40 sec (vs. less than 1 sec when I change same code to use Range.Text).

Question: is there any way to make Range.Copy/Range.Paste faster? All I need is to find a particular piece of text and copy it with all tables, formatting, etc. to another file.

Comment: There's a lot going on under the hood.  There are ways to limit the scope of the paste, but you just said in the question that you want to preserve all formatting and OLE automation, so.

Comment: @smirnov, Have you considered using OpenXML instead of Word interop? Word Interop is very quirky, it will require a specific setup and permissions set on each computer where it has to run, and Microsoft will change the requirements related to this on new Windows releases and/or service packs.

Comment: Setup is not an issue. It's about a small one-time desktop tool to enable a few internal users within the same organization to automate routine tasks with contract writing. When they do a change to a base contract, they take an existing doc of the contract, and a template for change, and copy various texts (dates, names, figures, etc.), incl. the scope of the contract (the subject of my question). The scope can incl. chapters, tables, etc. and therefore its format should be kept the same. It all works fine but because of slow copying, users have to wait about a minute to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy text with formatting in word you can use [FormattedText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.formattedtext.aspx) property of `Range` like

```
targetRange.FormattedText = sourceRange.FormattedText;
```

Avoid using Range.Copy() and Range.Paste() as this approach internally use clipboard this may cause security problems or may provide unpredictable results in some cases

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me. I tried that property before, but it failed because I used different Word.Application for target and source ranges and as I got only now, the FormattedText works with the same Application only.

Comment: @alex Thank you for pointing this out. I have the similar issue copying from one WORD doc to another, even on the same WORD.Application, is not working if I use range.FormattedText technique.